# Ignore Zero values in XY Line chart

Tags: jfreechart

I have a XY Line chart wherein I don't want to show the value zero eventhough the graph is plotted at the below i.e just ignorezerovalues as in stackedbar chart which works pretty good.

Update: Let me show you in detail. This is the data I have to plot where I have two ZERO values which shouldn't be displayed but plotted.

I have found a method in bar chart - `setignoreZeroValues()` that ignores the zeros in bar.

```
double data1[] = {0.0, 33.0, 44.0, 11.0, 77.0, 44.0,
    55.0, 66.0, 27.0, 99.0, 122.0, 0.0};
XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Last year", false);
for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    series1.add(data1[i], i);
}

XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
dataset.addSeries(series1);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Title", "Values",
    "", dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true,  true, false);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
String[] Cat = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"};
SymbolAxis rangeAxis = new SymbolAxis("Cat", Cat);
//rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
//rangeAxis.setRange(0,grade.length);
plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
```

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116548).

Comment: @trashgod : i have posted my small snippet below as answer as don't know how post it as comment.Any suggestion on this please.

Comment: Next time, please edit your question, don't post additional details as an answer

Comment: @nikoshr : Sorry and sure will do that since i am new to this awesome site.. Any suggestions on my question please?

Comment: @trashgod I tried using setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false) in rangeAxis.But that doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with `setAutoRangeStickyZero`?

Comment: No ..It doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid showing Zeros in generator? i have used this XYItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator("{1}", new DecimalFormat("0"), new DecimalFormat("0.00%"));
                renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
                renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);snippet.please advice

Comment: _At last found this which solved my problem:_ `renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition( ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.TOP_RIGHT));` you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).